# How to add Font Awesome fa-angle-right icon in my default bootstrap carousel?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel, font-awesome

Please take a look in the code.

```
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#my-slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
     <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#my-slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
     <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

Comment: I don't see any `fa-*` classes in here

Comment: That's the default bootstrap carousel code. What have you tried and what do you wish to achieve?

Comment: where should I add this fa-# for displaying icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include [FA](https://fontawesome.com/start) css in your html and use `<i class="fas fa-angle-right">` to add the arrow.

```
fa or fas = Font Awesome Solid
far = Font Awesome Regular
fal = Font Awesome Light
fab = Font Awesome Brands


<i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>  <!-- version 4's syntax -->

<i class="fas fa-camera-retro"></i> <!-- version 5's syntax -->
<i class="far fa-camera-retro"></i> <!-- example: regular style of camera-retro -->
<i class="fal fa-camera-retro"></i> <!-- example: light style of camera-retro -->
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#my-slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span>Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#my-slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> Next</span>
  </a>
```

Comment: fas means font awesome solid, fab means font awesome brand, far means font awesome regular, mention in brief

Answer (score 0):

Just include [font awesome](https://fontawesome.com/start) class on your page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#my-slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#my-slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span>Next<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>
  </a>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap 4 replace

```
 <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

with the FontAwesome tag

```
<i class="fa fa-angle-right">
```